# Parsing XML in Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, sql-server-ce

I have a following XML that I need to parse, but I am having some problems. First, the amount of  tags that I have inside Class tag is not known, and they not distinct (so I can't specify them by their name).

XML example:

```
<Class value="1B2">
    <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
    <FirstName>Jim</FirstName>
    <FirstName>Alice</FirstName>
    <FirstName>Jessica</FirstName>
    //(More similar lines, number is not known)
</Class>
<Class value="2C4">
    <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
    <FirstName>Jim</FirstName>
    <FirstName>Alice</FirstName>
    <FirstName>Jessica</FirstName>
    //(More similar lines, number is not known)
</Class>
```

Now this is my code so far to parse it:

Define xmlReader and XElement

```
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(modFunctions.InFName);
XElement xElem = new XElement("FirstName");
```

Then I am making connection to SQL Server CE database and this is my main loop that reads xmlfile:

```
while (xmlReader.Read())
{
    if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
        (xmlReader.LocalName == "Class" || xmlReader.LocalName == "FirstName") &&
        xmlReader.IsStartElement() == true)
    {
        // Find Class tag
        if (xmlReader.LocalName == "Class")
        {
            xElem = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(xmlReader);
            // Get 1B2 value
            HRName = xElem.FirstAttribute.Value;

            // Tried to read each node in xElement to get FirstName values.. this didn't work
            for ( (XNode e in (XNode)xElem)
            {
                string newString = ((string)xElem.Element("FirstName"));
            }

        }

        // Also tried this before, but it is skips it since FirstName tags are inside Class tag. 
        if (xmlReader.LocalName == "FirstName")
        {
            xElem = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(xmlReader);
            record.SetValue(0, xElem.Value);
            record.SetValue(1, HRName);
            rs.Insert(record);
        }
    }
}
```

And in my table (to where I am trying to write this) consists of two columns (FirstName and Class)

Comment: Check out linq-to-xml.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, Linq to Xml is your best bet: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq(v=vs.90).aspx

Your parse would look something like:

```
        string xml = "<root><Class value='1B2'><FirstName>Bob</FirstName><FirstName>Jim</FirstName><FirstName>Alice</FirstName><FirstName>Jessica</FirstName></Class>" +
                     "<Class value='2C4'><FirstName>Bob</FirstName><FirstName>Jim</FirstName><FirstName>Alice</FirstName><FirstName>Jessica</FirstName></Class></root>";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        foreach(var node in doc.Descendants("Class"))
        {
            var cls = node.Attribute("value").Value;
            string[] firstNames = node.Descendants("FirstName").Select(o => o.Value).ToArray();
        }
```